# Partial rendering failed with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, mongoid

I've an add_new_button which will create a new object in database and show the updated records with ajax. The code works well until I updated Mongoid from 2.4 => 3.0.0.rc (bundle update).

Now the problem is, when the button is clicked, the database is updated with new records, however the page won't be updated. I've checked the ajax request and it did render the partial page, but without the newly added record. While the second click will render the previously added record, yet without the latest record. Any ideas?

**Updated with code snippets**

It renders the _desktop.html.erb

```
#index.html.erb
<div id=columns>
    <%= render :partial => "desktop", :locals => { :items => @items } %>
</div>
```

*_desktop.html.erb* is rendered by the view and also for ajax update (This is the page which not updated with ajax)

```
#_desktop.html.erb
<%= form_tag(new_path, :remote => true) do %>
    <div class="m-body">
        <p>Select an item</p>
        <%= select_tag "user_items", options_from_collection_for_select(services, "id", "name", :prompt => true) %>
    </div>
    <div class="m-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <%= submit_tag "Confirm", :id => "add-item_btn" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

No problem in create a new item and it rendered _desktop.html.erb through json

```
# items_controller.rb
def new
    @user.items.create!(
        handle: 'name',
        content: 'body'
    )

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => {:sucess => true, :html => (render_to_string '_items.html.erb', :locals => { :items => @items })} }
        format.html {}
    end
end
```

However it does not fetch the updated html with the newly added item..

```
    <%# new.js.erb %>
    $('#add-item_btn').live('ajax:success', function(event, data){
    if(data.success == true) { $('#columns').html(data.html); }
});
```

Comment: showing your code pieces would help others to help you.

Comment: updated with code snippets, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem started with an update from a specific gem (in this case MongoID), then the first thing to consider is finding a CHANGELOG so see what could be the cause. In this case, **[it is a pretty long changelog](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**, but it is still your best bet to find the cause by yourself.

Also, MongoID has a pretty good **[upgrading guide](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/upgrading.html)** which might point you in the right direction.

One thing that did caught my eye, in `ItemsController#new`, you render `_items.html.erb` with local variables filled by `@items`. But where is `@items` set? With the code you provided, it looks like `@items` returns nil.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Still no idea after looking at the changelog, can't find any changes which would affect the render view. Anyway, I used `before_filter :get_items` in the ItemsController, so it is not nil.